# How to change the Bulky log messages when DEBUG = True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

If `DEBUG = True` then Flask shows bulky log messages like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO in Test.Api [C:\TEST\TestApi.py:114]:
Flask app starting on port 8086 ... 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where as If `DEBUG = False` or not set, then log messages are lighter like:

```
[2019-09-26 04:56:10,228] ERROR in Test.Api: This is an error message
```

How can I make the `debug = true` log messages appear like the 2nd case - without the extra hyphens and with time?

Comment: have you read [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/logging/)?
try removing default handler and use your own log formatter

Comment: Where does the doc say that DEBUG=True and False have different formatting?